# Send Bootstrap Modal Multiple Data From Multiple ASP Link Buttons

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I need some help figuring out how to pass data to a modal popup from muliple buttons.  I've created code that will do this for one button but I can't figure out how to make the jQuery generic to manage this from any button being clicked.  My ultimate goal is to get this working with an ASP dataview but I'll get this key piece working first.

Here is the jQuery.

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () { 
        var sTrainingSwipeID = $('#btnExtend_1').data('extend').TrainingSwipeID;
        var sCurrentDate = $('#btnExtend_1').data('extend').CurrentDate;

        $(".modal-body #TrainingSwipeID").val(sTrainingSwipeID);
        $(".modal-body #CurrentDate").val(sCurrentDate);
    });
</script>
```

Here are 2 link buttons that I'm playing with.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnExtend_1" href="#addBookDialog" runat="server" Text="Extend" 
    class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-outline-secondary btn-med" 
    data-extend='{"TrainingSwipeID":1,"CurrentDate":"03/07/2019"}' 
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="btnExtend_2" href="#addBookDialog" runat="server" Text="Extend" 
    class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-outline-secondary btn-med" 
    data-extend='{"TrainingSwipeID":2,"CurrentDate":"03/07/2017"}' 
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
```

Also here is the modal that I'm using.

```
<div runat="server" id="divButtonPopup">                 

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Extend Date</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body"> 
                <asp:HiddenField  ID="TrainingSwipeID" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="btnExtendFromModal" runat="server" Text="Extend" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnExtendDate_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-med" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
Here is the full code with edit suggestions from gaetanoM.  With this code the modal pops up from either button but nothing is contained in the TrainingSwipeID or CurrentDate text boxes in the modal.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Time Entry</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var ele = e.relatedTarget;
            var sTrainingSwipeID = $(ele).data('extend').TrainingSwipeID;
            var sCurrentDate = $(ele).data('extend').CurrentDate;

            $("#TrainingSwipeID").val(sTrainingSwipeID);
            $("#CurrentDate").val(sCurrentDate);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <a id="btnExtend_1" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-outline-secondary btn-med" href="#addBookDialog"
           data-extend='{"TrainingSwipeID":1,"CurrentDate":"03/07/2019"}'
           data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Extend1</a>
        <a id="btnExtend_2" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-outline-secondary btn-med" href="#addBookDialog"
           data-extend='{"TrainingSwipeID":2,"CurrentDate":"04/07/2017"}'
           data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Extend2</a>

        <div runat="server" id="divButtonPopup">

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <!-- Modal Header -->
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Extend Date</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Modal body -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="text"  id="TrainingSwipeID" />
                            <input type="text" id="CurrentDate" />

                        </div>
                        <!-- Modal footer -->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" id="btnExtendFromModal" class="btn btn-primary"
                                        OnClick="btnExtendDate_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal">Extend</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-med" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>   

    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to continue with the delegated event you need to change from:

```
var sTrainingSwipeID = $('#btnExtend_1').data('extend').TrainingSwipeID;
```

to:

```
var sTrainingSwipeID = $(this).data('extend').TrainingSwipeID;
```

For more info you can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

In any case, you may use [show.bs.modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) and in this case instead of **this** you need to use **event.relatedTarget**:

```js
$(function() {
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
     var ele = e.relatedTarget;
      var sTrainingSwipeID = $(ele).data('extend').TrainingSwipeID;
      var sCurrentDate = $(ele).data('extend').CurrentDate;

      $("#TrainingSwipeID").val(sTrainingSwipeID);
      $("#CurrentDate").val(sCurrentDate);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a id="btnExtend_1" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-outline-secondary btn-med" href="#addBookDialog"
   data-extend='{"TrainingSwipeID":1,"CurrentDate":"03/07/2019"}'
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#addBookDialog">Extend1</a>
<a id="btnExtend_2" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-outline-secondary btn-med" href="#addBookDialog"
   data-extend='{"TrainingSwipeID":2,"CurrentDate":"04/07/2017"}'
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#addBookDialog">Extend2</a>

<div runat="server" id="divButtonPopup">

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Extend Date</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text"  id="TrainingSwipeID">
                    <input type="text" id="CurrentDate">

                </div>
                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnExtendFromModal" class="btn btn-primary"
                                OnClick="btnExtendDate_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal">Extend</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-med" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @gaetanoM.  I updated my post with your code suggestions but it still doesn't work.  When I click either button the modal pops up but with nothing in the fields.

Comment: you need to wrap the js code into [dom ready event](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Snippet updated to show you the change